# Kernel debugging from /dev/kmsg

Tags: linux, kernel, debugging

I am having some problem with a (customized) driver (smsc95xx) which runs on my embedded systems, and I would need to understand where the issue exactely comes from.

For example, this is a kernel error message from /dev/kmsg reporting the issue:

```
1,737,1433656890,-;Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 000001a0
1,738,1433665618,-;pgd = daafc000
1,739,1433668609,-;[000001a0] *pgd=9d5dd831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
0,740,1433675720,-;Internal error: Oops: 17 [#2] SMP ARM
4,741,1433680664,-;Modules linked in: ctr ccm ecb hci_uart rfcomm bnep bluetooth arc4 usb_trimble(O) wl18xx wlcore mac80211 cfg80211 rfkill wlcore_sdio twl4030_madc industrialio ftdi_sio smsc95xx(O) usbserial(O) ipv6
4,742,1433700378,-;CPU: 0 PID: 17418 Comm: sh Tainted: G      D    O   3.18.18-custom #20
4,743,1433708343,-;task: de30cd40 ti: da9b8000 task.ti: da9b8000
4,744,1433714050,-;PC is at __pm_runtime_resume+0x1c/0x64
4,745,1433719085,-;LR is at usb_autopm_get_interface+0x18/0x5c
4,746,1433724578,-;pc : [<c03cb590>]    lr : [<c04677d4>]    psr: 20000013\x0asp : da9b9ea8  ip : da9b9f14  fp : 00000000
4,747,1433736633,-;r10: daa22a4c  r9 : 00000024  r8 : 00000004
4,748,1433742126,-;r7 : 000000a0  r6 : 00000004  r5 : 00000000  r4 : 00000020
4,749,1433748992,-;r3 : 000001a0  r2 : 00000040  r1 : 00000004  r0 : 00000020
4,750,1433755859,-;Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
4,751,1433763366,-;Control: 10c5387d  Table: 9aafc019  DAC: 00000015
0,752,1433769378,-;Process sh (pid: 17418, stack limit = 0xda9b8240)
0,753,1433775421,-;Stack: (0xda9b9ea8 to 0xda9ba000)
0,754,1433779998,-;9ea0:                   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000020 000000a0 c04677d4
0,755,1433788604,-;9ec0: dd31f680 00000000 00000040 c04574c8 c01ae218 c0085f58 00000001 00000000
0,756,1433797210,-;9ee0: 00000000 00000024 c04574a0 dd31f680 c0457510 de687a00 da9b9f88 bf0d44e4
0,757,1433805816,-;9f00: 00000024 da9b9f14 00000004 de687a00 da9b9f88 01110000 00000000 bf0d7990
0,758,1433814422,-;9f20: bf0d7cbc 00000000 00000000 bf0d4554 00000002 00000002 daa22a40 c01ae24c
0,759,1433823028,-;9f40: 00000000 00000000 dd3721c0 00000002 000eb408 da9b9f88 c000e824 da9b8000
0,760,1433831634,-;9f60: 00000000 c0145fd8 de30cd40 c08f20d4 dd3721c0 dd3721c0 00000002 000eb408
0,761,1433840240,-;9f80: c000e824 c01464e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002 000eb408 b6ee1d60
0,762,1433848815,-;9fa0: 00000004 c000e660 00000002 000eb408 00000001 000eb408 00000002 00000000
0,763,1433857421,-;9fc0: 00000002 000eb408 b6ee1d60 00000004 00000000 000e515c 00000001 00000000
0,764,1433865997,-;9fe0: 00000000 beaef904 b6e1946c b6e7139c 60000010 00000001 00000000 00000000
4,765,1433874603,-;[<c03cb590>] (__pm_runtime_resume) from [<c04677d4>] (usb_autopm_get_interface+0x18/0x5c)
4,766,1433884307,-;[<c04677d4>] (usb_autopm_get_interface) from [<c04574c8>] (usbnet_write_cmd+0x28/0x70)
4,767,1433893737,-;[<c04574c8>] (usbnet_write_cmd) from [<bf0d44e4>] (__smsc95xx_write_reg+0x50/0x8c [smsc95xx])
4,768,1433903839,-;[<bf0d44e4>] (__smsc95xx_write_reg [smsc95xx]) from [<bf0d4554>] (smsc95xx_store+0x34/0x218 [smsc95xx])
4,769,1433914794,-;[<bf0d4554>] (smsc95xx_store [smsc95xx]) from [<c01ae24c>] (kernfs_fop_write+0xc0/0x184)
4,770,1433924438,-;[<c01ae24c>] (kernfs_fop_write) from [<c0145fd8>] (vfs_write+0xa0/0x1ac)
4,771,1433932586,-;[<c0145fd8>] (vfs_write) from [<c01464e0>] (SyS_write+0x44/0x9c)
4,772,1433940002,-;[<c01464e0>] (SyS_write) from [<c000e660>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x50)
0,773,1433947967,-;Code: e1a04000 0a000006 e2803d06 f5d3f000 (e1932f9f) 
4,774,1433954650,-;---[ end trace bdd277dec40e1d5c ]---
```

I suppose the most important part are the last few lines:

```
4,765,1433874603,-;[<c03cb590>] (__pm_runtime_resume) from [<c04677d4>] (usb_autopm_get_interface+0x18/0x5c)
4,766,1433884307,-;[<c04677d4>] (usb_autopm_get_interface) from [<c04574c8>] (usbnet_write_cmd+0x28/0x70)
4,767,1433893737,-;[<c04574c8>] (usbnet_write_cmd) from [<bf0d44e4>] (__smsc95xx_write_reg+0x50/0x8c [smsc95xx])
4,768,1433903839,-;[<bf0d44e4>] (__smsc95xx_write_reg [smsc95xx]) from [<bf0d4554>] (smsc95xx_store+0x34/0x218 [smsc95xx])
4,769,1433914794,-;[<bf0d4554>] (smsc95xx_store [smsc95xx]) from [<c01ae24c>] (kernfs_fop_write+0xc0/0x184)
4,770,1433924438,-;[<c01ae24c>] (kernfs_fop_write) from [<c0145fd8>] (vfs_write+0xa0/0x1ac)
4,771,1433932586,-;[<c0145fd8>] (vfs_write) from [<c01464e0>] (SyS_write+0x44/0x9c)
4,772,1433940002,-;[<c01464e0>] (SyS_write) from [<c000e660>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x50)
```

but maybe there is a better way than checking /dev/kmsg to understand this output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The driver was modified to create the files into the

```
/sys/class/dirnamae/files
```

directory (where dirname and files are named into the driver's code).
The problem was that the driver did not delete the directory previously created, so unplugging and replugging the device and then writing into the files was causing the kernel error showed before, because it's like writing into a memory area which is not referenced any more.

The solution is to delete the

```
/sys/class/dirnamae
```

and recreating it every time the device is unplugged.